# a socket and queue problem

Tags: c++, sockets, queue

I have some  code:

a declaration of a queue:

```
typedef deque<char*, allocator<char*> > CHARDEQUE;
typedef queue<char*,CHARDEQUE> CHARQUEUE;

CHARQUEUE p;
size_t size_q;
char recv_data[1024];
```

I use a udp socket to receive data from a distant machine:

this is the loop:

```
while (1)
{

        bytes_read = recvfrom(sock,recv_data,1024,0, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &addr_len);

        p.push(recv_data);
        size_q=p.size();
        printf("%d\n",size_q);


    }
```

but the problem is that the size of queue doesen't grow it's always the same, this is what I see on the screen

```
 0
    40
    40
    40
    40
    40
    ...
```

for more information, my program is receiving raw data, that's why i use char array..
any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: You're pushing the same pointer into the queue, you're not pushing the data that it points to.

Comment: by this I thought I'm copying data to the queue...if not how do you think I can do that..would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sizeof` is determined in compilation time. You probably mean something like `p.size()`.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(p)` does not return the number of elements in the queue ! It is a compile time construct that returns the number of bytes occupied by the `CHARQUEUE` type : `sizeof(p)` with *always* give you the same result.

What you need is :

```
std::cout << p.size() << std::endl;
```

Just to illustrate this with another example : `const char *s = "Something";` is a pointer to a null terminated string, and `sizeof(s)` (which is equivalent to `sizeof(const char *)`) has nothing to do with the actual length of the string `strlen(s)` (which in this case is 9).

Answer (score 0):

another problem, besides the sizeof/p.size() thing is that p.push(recv_data) is pushing the address of recv_data buffer into the queue, not the data itself